# How to trigger on new data async fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to trigger on new item in data ? async fetch in react/redux

Need to highlight new item which came and play song on event

I tried make it

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.props.notify != nextProps.notify) { //play song }
}
```

But with exmaple above it trigger once when component loads first data

Comment: Redux should do this automatically so the issue is likely somewhere in your component or action or reducer. Please post more of your code

Comment: Is your component wrapped in a parent component which passes the props to this component ? And is the nextprops nested into the props of the parent component ? Need more code to understand what is the real issue

Comment: Looks like you would need to learn some basics on how a React application is working, as mentioned above, a parent component will perform the fetch call, then propagate the results to its child components by passing appropriate data in their props.